# How was an answer posted after the question was closed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions, answers

I looked at [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/differences-between-building-a-custom-blog-vs-building-a-blog-on-blogger) not long after it had been asked and it had already been put "on hold". There were no answers.

However, sometime later I happened open the question again, but now there was an answer! Checking the timestamps of the answer ("2017-07-31 **16:52:42**Z") and when the question was closed ("2017-07-31 **16:35:57**Z") does appear to show that the answer was indeed posted *after* the question was closed - some 17 minutes after - how is this possible?!

Comment: I don't know how it could happen, but the question's admin timeline that is available to moderators appears to confirm that it was closed and then answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible):

> We give people a server side grace period to answer questions, even if the question gets closed.
>
> If the client side checks fail, for whatever reason, and someone does post an answer, we will accept it (for a while).

[and](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed):

> If a question is closed while you're answering on the full version of the site, you will receive a notification that the question was closed and the 'Post Your Answer' button will be disabled. However, this is only a client-side restriction, so it is possible in some cases that this process fails.
>
> When it does, the backend allows for a grace period of around four hours (previously there was no time limit). Presumably the client-side restriction did fail in this case, and since the answer was "in-flight", as Jeff describes it, the server accepted it despite the question already having been closed.
>
> For users answering from a mobile device, there's no client-side restriction in place to begin with, so this situation is presumably even easier to create when using the mobile version of the site.
>
> As a side note, this apparently even works for questions closed due to migration.

Comment: Ah haa - thanks! And that answer was posted just over an hour after the question was asked - well within the 4 hour limit! "For users answering from a mobile device, there's no client-side restriction in place" - since that was answered over 6 years ago, do you know if that is still the case? Presumably this is refering to the mobile _website_, rather than the mobile _app_? Since, the Android/iOS (official) apps haven't been around that long - or is this something which has been carried through to a "feature" of the mobile apps as well?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. But based on the phrasing, "mobile version of the site" I'm guessing this applies to the website. But I wouldn't be 100% confident in saying that.